# How to receive data from LoRa App server?

Tags: go, lora, lorawan

I collect data from the LoRa node, and then gateway forward to lora server, at last, the data to the lora app server. but i cannot find the following interface.
(https://docs.loraserver.io/lora-app-server/integrate/data/)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAQMf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a MQTT client (or user a command-line one, like mosquitto_sub, as suggested in https://docs.loraserver.io/lora-app-server/integrate/data/) and then subscribe to the receiving topic for the specified node. The image you posted is not an interface but an example message a node will send through the topic. For the case given, appID is "123" and devEUI is "0202020202020202", so you need to subscribe to the following topic to get messages from the node:

application/123/node/0202020202020202/rx

As said, you may consume the messages through a MQTT client (there are plenty of clients for different languages), or from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating from current versions.

Global integrations
Global integrations are configured through the lora-app-server.toml configuration file and are globally enabled. This means that for every application configured, the application will be published using this / these integration(s).

The following integrations are available:

MQTT
AWS Simple Notification Service
Azure Service Bus
Google Cloud Platform Pub/Sub
Application integrations
Additional to the globally enabled integrations, it is also possible to set up integrations per application.

The following integrations are available:

HTTP
InfluxDB

From: [loraserver.io](https://www.loraserver.io/lora-app-server/integrate/sending-receiving/)